# The first coordinates never work, but the following work

Tags: python

This is not full code, but the question is in coordinates. The first time you type coords, code just ignore them, but if you type the same coords second time, code will work properly. Help please

```
b = input()
coords = b.split()
coordinates_x = int(coords[0])
coordinates_y = int(coords[1])

new_list = [x for x in a]
for i in range(3):
    line_1.append(new_list[i])
    line_2.append(new_list[i + 3])
    line_3.append(new_list[i + 6])

# залупа ебаная
while True:
    b = input()
    coords = b.split()
    coordinates_x = int(coords[0])
    coordinates_y = int(coords[1])
    if (3 >= coordinates_y >= 1) and (3 >= coordinates_x >= 1):
        if coordinates_x == 1:
            if new_list[coordinates_y - 1] == "_":
                new_list[coordinates_y - 1] = "X"
                pechat(new_list)
                break
            elif new_list[coordinates_y - 1] == "X" or new_list[coordinates_y - 1] == "0":
                print("This cell is occupied! Choose another one!")
                continue
        elif coordinates_x == 2:
            if new_list[coordinates_y + 2] == "_":
                new_list[coordinates_y + 2] = "X"
                pechat(new_list)
                break
            elif new_list[coordinates_y + 2] == "X" or new_list[coordinates_y + 2] == "O":
                print("This cell is occupied! Choose another one!")
                continue
        elif coordinates_x == 3:
            if new_list[coordinates_y + 5] == "_":
                new_list[coordinates_y + 5] = "X"
                pechat(new_list)
                break
            elif new_list[coordinates_y + 5] == "X" or new_list[coordinates_y + 5] == "O":
                print("This cell is occupied! Choose another one!")
                continue
    elif (3 < coordinates_y or coordinates_y < 1) or (3 < coordinates_x or coordinates_x < 1):
        print("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those first four lines:

```
b = input()
coords = b.split()
coordinates_x = int(coords[0])
coordinates_y = int(coords[1])
```

just take input and do nothing with it. That's why the first coords you enter don't do anything. Just remove those lines and it should work.

The code inside the `while` loop takes the input and actually runs the calculations on it, so you must leave it in place. The 4 at the top look like leftovers from an earlier version of the program before the while loop.

Comment: I have already got it, but thank you anyway. I wanted to cut this part, when put in While loop. As I can see, I have just copied it instead of cut....